# Application is crashing while calling camera.setParameters(parameters);

Tags: android, camera

In my android application I am using custom camera with effects. While i am calling

```
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

the application is working well but while I am calling

```
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_BLACKBOARD);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

the application leads to the following exception

```
01-21 17:32:13.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5932): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
01-21 17:32:13.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5932):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
01-21 17:32:13.656: E/AndroidRuntime(5932):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1494)
```

Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: did you manage to solve that thread?

Answer (score 1):

> It means the `EFFECT_BLACKBOARD` is not supported by your device. You must check whether the `ColorEffect` is supported by your Device.

```
CameraParameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
```

And check if it contains your effect then apply it.